# I want a format control button to check if a format control checkbox is clicked and then delete a specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Makro1()

If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Kontrollkästchen 2").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End If

End Sub
```

I just have no idea what i am doing wrong. I have a format control checkbox in Sheet 1 ( I don't want to use ActiveX). Then i have a button linked to Makro1. When i click the button i want the makro to check if the checkbox is clicked and if that is the case, delte Worksheet "Sheet2".

I would be very happy if someone could help me as im not very familiar with makros.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if my answer is correct accept it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but the correct VBA code is:

```
Sub Makro1()

If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Kontrollkästchen 2").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
 End If
 
End Sub
```